# SQL - How do I add a count to my table which has been a result from a query

Tags: sql, sas

I've retrieved a count of the duplicates and their occurrences using the below code

```
select empID, count(empID) AS DUPLICATEempID
from employees
group by empID
having count (empID) > 1
```

I now want the table to include the number of rows returned (i.e. insert the number on the table returned)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using SAS...........

Answer (score 2):

In SAS, you can do this with a subquery:

```
select empId, DUPLICateempID, count(*) as NumDuplicates
from (select empID, count(empID) AS DUPLICATEempID
      from employees
      group by empID
      having count (empID) > 1
     ) t
```

When you have an aggregation function without a `group by`, it applies the function to the whole table and re-merges the results.